# Word premium applies to 2 words?

Tags: scrabble

We had a family scrabble game that erupted into a debate.  I have searched these forums, and while I found several threads that seemed to apply to this scenario, it wasn’t quite clear.

The question is whether or not a premium word square (double or triple words) applies to all words created during the current play or not.  I’ll attempt to articulate the scenario.

First move:  TO was played vertically.

Second move:  FREES was played horizontally and the E of FREES created TOE.  The S of FREES landed on a double word square.

Question:  The current play resulted in two new words, TOE and FREES.  Does the double word on the S of FREES count for both words or just FREES?  If not, why not?

The rules don’t seem to address this scenario when two words are created or under what conditions thus applies or doesn’t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Scrabble rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) (emphasis mine):

> Premium Word Squares: The score for an **entire word is doubled when
>   one of its letters is placed on a pink square: it is tripled when one
>   of its letters is placed on a red square.** Include premiums for
>   double or triple letter values, if any, before doubling or tripling
>   the word score. If a word is formed that covers two premium word
>   squares, the score is doubled and then re-doubled (4 times the letter
>   count), or tripled and then re-tripled (9 times the letter count).
>   NOTE: the center square is a pink square, which doubles the score for
>   the first word.

Double and triple word spaces only count for words which have one of their letters on that space.  In your example, TOE doesn't have any letters on the new double word square so it doesn't count.

<sub>Side note: if it was meant to double all the points in a turn, I would have expected it to be labeled as "Double Turn Score" or some such thing.</sub>